# Correct taxonomy field to use in EditModePanel?

Tags: taxonomy, managed-metadata, page-layout

We have a SharePoint 2010 content type with a ManagedMetaData field bound to a custom TermStore/Set in the Managed Metadata Service.

We are using an EditModePanel on the PageLayout for the content type and I can't get the correct field to show for the taxonomy picker.

I've added a TaxonomyWebTaggingControl but it appears that I need to hardcode the SSPId and TermSetId values in the layout, which I can't do as I don't know them.

In the Feature which contains the content type we have an event receiver which binds the field to the termset but which control do I need to use in the pagelayout to allow this to be edited?

(It works fine if I edit an item directly from the list using the default SharePoint form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working in the end. There's a helpful post here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/310692d3-49f2-4c0f-b911-735f24b769b3

Basically you have to add a note column and use TaxonomyField.TextFieldId to point your Taxonomy field to the note field.

I was also using the wrong control in my Page layout, I should have used a TaxonomyFieldControl, not a TaxonomyWebTaggingControl.

Answer (score -1):

I am intereseted in knowing this aswell. I am basicly doing the exact same thing. Seeing as I dont have a code behind page for my page layout I have not found a good way to this.

Previously I have used it within web parts og application pages. I dont know if this will help you but the code I have used for connecting to the service is this:

```
SPContext context = SPContext.Current;
                                                     SPSite site = context.Site;
                                                     TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);

                                                     TermStore termStore =
                                                         session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
                                                     Group group = termStore.Groups["groupname"];
                                                     TermSet productsTermSet = group.TermSets["termsetname"];

                                                     enheterTaxonomyTagger.SspId.Add(termStore.Id);
                                                     enheterTaxonomyTagger.TermSetId.Add(productsTermSet.Id);
                                                     enheterTaxonomyTagger.IsAddTerms = false;
                                                     enheterTaxonomyTagger.AllowFillIn = false;
                                                     enheterTaxonomyTagger.IsMulti = true;

                                                     portefoljeTaxonomyTagger.SspId.Add(termStore.Id);
                                                     portefoljeTaxonomyTagger.TermSetId.Add(productsTermSet.Id);
                                                     portefoljeTaxonomyTagger.IsAddTerms = false;
                                                     portefoljeTaxonomyTagger.AllowFillIn = false;
                                                     portefoljeTaxonomyTagger.IsMulti = false;
```